# Text width limit, with wraps

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, text, text-width

In a rails app of mine i'm building an app using the feeds , i'm modifying the layout of a page , the feeds' text limit is of 140 characters and the window which contains the text is 63em width.
If the text is long enough (50/60 characters) it will spread out the window, i want that after a certain number n of characters the text will wraps and continue in another line, for example if that number n is 6 and i insert the text

```
hi my name is davide
```

when it has given as output it will became

```
hi my na
me is davide
```

if you know even how to include spaces and how to don't break words (name --> na me), please tell me , it would be better.

here's the code which gives the feeds in output

```
<body align="center">
    <div class="dialog">
        <h1>La Grande Guerra</h1>
    </div>

    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Nuovo Feed', new_feed_path %>
    </p>

    <% @feeds.each do |feed| %>
      <p>
          <b>Data di pubblicazione: </b><%= feed.date %><br><br>
          <b>Feed:</b><br><br>
          <%= feed.feed_text %><br><br>
          <%= link_to 'Mostra', feed %>
          <%= link_to 'Modifica', edit_feed_path(feed) %>
          <%= link_to 'Elimina', feed, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
          <a href="http://localhost:3000">Torna all'inizio<br></a>
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <br>

  </body>
```

and this is how i create the "windows" (i took this code from the error 404 page)

```
div.dialog 
    {
      width: 55em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-left-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #BBB;
      border-top: #B00100 solid 4px;
      border-top-left-radius: 9px;
      border-top-right-radius: 9px;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 7px 4em 0 4em;

    }

    body > p 
    {
      width: 63em;
      margin: 0 auto 1em;
      padding: 1em 0;
      background-color: #F7F7F7;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      border-top-color: #DADADA;
      color: #666;
      box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);
      color:black;
    }
```

Comment: I think the closest you can come with pure css is using `word-wrap:break-word` but that would involve you replacing all spaces with non breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) - http://jsfiddle.net/Y3M8z/, otherwise your best bet would be to use javascript and insert a `br` every six characters

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
   body > p 
        {
          width: 63em;
          margin: 0 auto 1em;
          padding: 1em 0;
          background-color: #F7F7F7;
          border: 1px solid #CCC;
          border-right-color: #999;
          border-bottom-color: #999;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
          border-top-color: #DADADA;
          color: #666;
          box-shadow:0 3px 8px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.17);
          color:black;

 -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;

     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
        }
```